# Prize/Gift selection campaign

Tags: layout, input

I'm trying to plan a wireframe/site that allows new registered users to reclaim a reward for registering. There are 3 very different rewards they can pick. Sort of like when you register an Adobe product you can pick a few different things like Lynda subscription for a month and the like.

The users' path would be something like this;

1. They have signed up for a service in the last 2 months, or possibly that day.
2. Receive an email that outlines each reward, directs them to website
3. Go to website, enter in their member number and postcode
4. They can pick 1 of 3 rewards
5. They receive a confirmation email

My question is, is there a term for this type of marketing, and is there a term in UX for this? And, does anybody know of any examples of this that could help?

Comment: Hi tehk. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here. If it's the name of this type of UX flow then I'm not sure there *is* a term for this, it's just a user journey. Why do you wish to know this term? Instead of trying to find the term for a situation, why not explain what the problem is you're trying to solve and we'll see if we can help you out there. That's more what we're about on ux.stackexchange rather than just giving you examples of sites that do something similar (that's not really something we can help with - we provide answers to problems, rather than links to numerous examples).

Comment: You might be referring to Persuasion/Choice Architecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_architecture), which is like designing to influence certain task completion, right? I think User Experience would be linked to this in ways that you want to make it easy for the user to move towards the completion of a task with minimal friction on the UI side...

Answer (score 1):

A **reward program** usually involves a longer lasting customer relationship, where the reward strengthens the customer's bond to the product, brand or company. Essentially though, your scheme is a mere **bonus** or **addon**.

I am not sure, if there is a *user experience* specific to this, but **direct marketing**, or more specifically **email marketing**, obviously requires remote interaction with the user as well as the user's interaction with your web interface.